# Running 'GoToAssist' in Citrix without 'administrative permissions'

Tags: permissions, uac

We are offering our customers a personal desktop within a central Citrix farm.

Now some of these customers use vendors that demand the use of GoToAssist for support. My question is if anyone can recommend a safe way to allow specific users with 'user permissions' to install and eventually run this software (which requires administrative permissions).

- Installing this software in our golden image would be an option but isn't preferred.
- We have an App-V environment which could be used to virtualize GoToAssist (haven't looked into it yet)